# Need a jquery call that will ensure only unique items in a UL

Tags: jquery

Everything under h3 should be unique.  For example, if we find this one `<h3>Vanderbilt Charter Academy</h3>`, we should remove any other li in the list that contains the same thing.

Everything under h3 should be unique. For example, if we find this one `

```
  <h3>Vanderbilt Charter Academy</h3>`, we should remove any other li in the list that
  contains the same thing.


  <div id="cbqwpctl00_ctl24_g_a16e8b8c_a97b_4776_8dc2_f1e731034df0" class=
  "cbq-layout-main">
    <ul class="dfwp-column dfwp-list" style="width:100%">
      <li class="dfwp-item">
        <div class="MiddleContent WebPartFloatLeft">
          <h3>Vanderbilt Charter Academy</h3>

          <p>Ivan Kraker<br />
          <br />
          ,&nbsp;,&nbsp;<br /></p>

          <p><a href=""></a><br />
          <a href="mailto:"></a></p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="dfwp-item">
        <div class="MiddleContent WebPartFloatRight">
          <h3>Aspire Charter Academy</h3>

          <p>Gloria McDaniel Hall<br />
          <br />
          ,&nbsp;,&nbsp;<br /></p>

          <p><a href=""></a><br />
          <a href="mailto:"></a></p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="dfwp-item">
        <div class="WebPartFloatClear">
          &nbsp;
        </div>

        <div class="MiddleContent WebPartFloatLeft">
          <h3>Great Oaks Academy</h3>

          <p>Ricky Fountain<br />
          <br />
          ,&nbsp;,&nbsp;<br /></p>

          <p><a href=""></a><br />
          <a href="mailto:"></a></p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="dfwp-item">
        <div class="MiddleContent WebPartFloatRight">
          <h3>Keystone Academy</h3>

          <p>Jaclyn Jeffrey<br />
          <br />
          ,&nbsp;,&nbsp;<br /></p>

          <p><a href=""></a><br />
          <a href="mailto:"></a></p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="dfwp-item">
        <div class="WebPartFloatClear">
          &nbsp;
        </div>

        <div class="MiddleContent WebPartFloatLeft">
          <h3>PreEminent Charter School</h3>

          <p>Michael Stack<br />
          <br />
          ,&nbsp;,&nbsp;<br /></p>

          <p><a href=""></a><br />
          <a href="mailto:"></a></p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="dfwp-item">
        <div class="MiddleContent WebPartFloatRight">
          <h3>Excel Charter Academy</h3>

          <p>Dan Bartels<br />
          <br />
          ,&nbsp;,&nbsp;<br /></p>

          <p><a href=""></a><br />
          <a href="mailto:"></a></p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="dfwp-item">
        <div class="WebPartFloatClear">
          &nbsp;
        </div>

        <div class="MiddleContent WebPartFloatLeft">
          <h3>Vanguard Charter Academy</h3>

          <p>Daryl Vriesenga<br />
          <br />
          ,&nbsp;,&nbsp;<br /></p>

          <p><a href=""></a><br />
          <a href="mailto:"></a></p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="dfwp-item">
        <div class="MiddleContent WebPartFloatRight">
          <h3>Vanderbilt Charter Academy</h3>

          <p>Ivan Kraker<br />
          <br />
          ,&nbsp;,&nbsp;<br /></p>

          <p><a href=""></a><br />
          <a href="mailto:"></a></p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="dfwp-item">
        <div class="WebPartFloatClear">
          &nbsp;
        </div>

        <div class="MiddleContent WebPartFloatLeft">
          <h3>Queen's Grant Community School</h3>

          <p>Christy Morrin<br />
          <br />
          ,&nbsp;,&nbsp;<br /></p>

          <p><a href=""></a><br />
          <a href="mailto:"></a></p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="dfwp-item">
        <div class="MiddleContent WebPartFloatRight">
          <h3>Knapp Charter Academy</h3>

          <p>Jami Hoeksema<br />
          <br />
          ,&nbsp;,&nbsp;<br /></p>

          <p><a href=""></a><br />
          <a href="mailto:"></a></p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="dfwp-item">
        <div class="WebPartFloatClear">
          &nbsp;
        </div>

        <div class="MiddleContent WebPartFloatLeft">
          <h3>Forsyth Academy</h3>

          <p>Lori Hill<br />
          <br />
          ,&nbsp;,&nbsp;<br /></p>

          <p><a href=""></a><br />
          <a href="mailto:"></a></p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="dfwp-item">
        <div class="MiddleContent WebPartFloatRight">
          <h3>Stambaugh Charter Academy</h3>

          <p>Alan Harper<br />
          <br />
          ,&nbsp;,&nbsp;<br /></p>

          <p><a href=""></a><br />
          <a href="mailto:"></a></p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="dfwp-item">
        <div class="WebPartFloatClear">
          &nbsp;
        </div>

        <div class="MiddleContent WebPartFloatLeft">
          <h3>Warrendale Charter Academy</h3>

          <p>Brigitte Brown<br />
          <br />
          ,&nbsp;,&nbsp;<br /></p>

          <p><a href=""></a><br />
          <a href="mailto:"></a></p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="dfwp-item">
        <div class="MiddleContent WebPartFloatRight">
          <h3>Walker Charter Academy</h3>

          <p>Steve Bagley<br />
          <br />
          ,&nbsp;,&nbsp;<br /></p>

          <p><a href=""></a><br />
          <a href="mailto:"></a></p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="dfwp-item">
        <div class="WebPartFloatClear">
          &nbsp;
        </div>

        <div class="MiddleContent WebPartFloatLeft">
          <h3>Cross Creek Charter Academy</h3>

          <p>Joe Nieuwkoop<br />
          <br />
          ,&nbsp;,&nbsp;<br /></p>

          <p><a href=""></a><br />
          <a href="mailto:"></a></p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="dfwp-item">
        <div class="MiddleContent WebPartFloatRight">
          <h3>Vanderbilt Charter Academy</h3>

          <p>Ivan Kraker<br />
          <br />
          ,&nbsp;,&nbsp;<br /></p>

          <p><a href=""></a><br />
          <a href="mailto:"></a></p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="dfwp-item">
        <div class="WebPartFloatClear">
          &nbsp;
        </div>

        <div class="MiddleContent WebPartFloatLeft">
          <h3>Walton Charter Academy</h3>

          <p>John Brillhart<br />
          <br />
          ,&nbsp;,&nbsp;<br /></p>

          <p><a href=""></a><br />
          <a href="mailto:"></a></p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="dfwp-item">
        <div class="MiddleContent WebPartFloatRight">
          <h3>Winterfield Venture Academy</h3>

          <p>Amy Kramer<br />
          <br />
          ,&nbsp;,&nbsp;<br /></p>

          <p><a href=""></a><br />
          <a href="mailto:"></a></p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="dfwp-item">
        <div class="WebPartFloatClear">
          &nbsp;
        </div>

        <div class="MiddleContent WebPartFloatLeft">
          <h3>Hamtramck Academy</h3>

          <p>Stephanie Glenn<br />
          <br />
          ,&nbsp;,&nbsp;<br /></p>

          <p><a href=""></a><br />
          <a href="mailto:"></a></p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="dfwp-item">
        <div class="MiddleContent WebPartFloatRight">
          <h3>Eagle Crest Charter Academy</h3>

          <p>Daniel Harris<br />
          <br />
          ,&nbsp;,&nbsp;<br /></p>

          <p><a href=""></a><br />
          <a href="mailto:"></a></p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="dfwp-item">
        <div class="WebPartFloatClear">
          &nbsp;
        </div>

        <div class="MiddleContent WebPartFloatLeft">
          <h3>Buffalo United Charter School</h3>

          <p>Tammy Messmer<br />
          <br />
          ,&nbsp;,&nbsp;<br /></p>

          <p><a href=""></a><br />
          <a href="mailto:"></a></p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="dfwp-item">
        <div class="MiddleContent WebPartFloatRight">
          <h3>Aspire Charter Academy</h3>

          <p>Gloria McDaniel-Hall<br />
          <br />
          ,&nbsp;,&nbsp;<br /></p>

          <p><a href=""></a><br />
          <a href="mailto:"></a></p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="dfwp-item">
        <div class="WebPartFloatClear">
          &nbsp;
        </div>

        <div class="MiddleContent WebPartFloatLeft">
          <h3>Hamtramck Academy</h3>

          <p>Stephanie Glenn<br />
          <br />
          ,&nbsp;,&nbsp;<br /></p>

          <p><a href=""></a><br />
          <a href="mailto:"></a></p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="dfwp-item">
        <div class="MiddleContent WebPartFloatRight">
          <h3>Apex Academy</h3>

          <p>Karl Boland<br />
          <br />
          ,&nbsp;,&nbsp;<br /></p>

          <p><a href=""></a><br />
          <a href="mailto:"></a></p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="dfwp-item">
        <div class="WebPartFloatClear">
          &nbsp;
        </div>

        <div class="MiddleContent WebPartFloatLeft">
          <h3>Linden Charter Academy</h3>

          <p>Linda Caine-Smith<br />
          <br />
          ,&nbsp;,&nbsp;<br /></p>

          <p><a href=""></a><br />
          <a href="mailto:"></a></p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="dfwp-item">
        <div class="MiddleContent WebPartFloatRight">
          <h3>Burton Glen Charter Academy</h3>

          <p>Shawn Merriweather<br />
          <br />
          ,&nbsp;,&nbsp;<br /></p>

          <p><a href=""></a><br />
          <a href="mailto:"></a></p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="dfwp-item">
        <div class="WebPartFloatClear">
          &nbsp;
        </div>

        <div class="MiddleContent WebPartFloatLeft">
          <h3>Aspire Charter Academy</h3>

          <p>Gloria McDaniel-Hall<br />
          <br />
          ,&nbsp;,&nbsp;<br /></p>

          <p><a href=""></a><br />
          <a href="mailto:"></a></p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="dfwp-item">
        <div class="MiddleContent WebPartFloatRight">
          <h3>Brooklyn Excelsior Charter School</h3>

          <p>Thomas DeMarco<br />
          <br />
          ,&nbsp;,&nbsp;<br /></p>

          <p><a href=""></a><br />
          <a href="mailto:"></a></p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="dfwp-item">
        <div class="WebPartFloatClear">
          &nbsp;
        </div>

        <div class="MiddleContent WebPartFloatLeft">
          <p>Catherine Witt<br />
          <br />
          ,&nbsp;,&nbsp;<br /></p>

          <p><a href=""></a><br />
          <a href="mailto:"></a></p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="dfwp-item">
        <div class="MiddleContent WebPartFloatRight">
          <h3>Prevail Academy</h3>

          <p>Jodi Donkin<br />
          <br />
          ,&nbsp;,&nbsp;<br /></p>

          <p><a href=""></a><br />
          <a href="mailto:"></a></p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="dfwp-item">
        <div class="WebPartFloatClear">
          &nbsp;
        </div>

        <div class="MiddleContent WebPartFloatLeft">
          <h3>Paramount Charter Academy</h3>

          <p>Kathleen Grinwis<br />
          <br />
          ,&nbsp;,&nbsp;<br /></p>

          <p><a href=""></a><br />
          <a href="mailto:"></a></p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="dfwp-item">
        <div class="MiddleContent WebPartFloatRight">
          <h3>Achieve Charter Academy</h3>

          <p>Claudia Williamson<br />
          <br />
          ,&nbsp;,&nbsp;<br /></p>

          <p><a href=""></a><br />
          <a href="mailto:"></a></p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="dfwp-item">
        <div class="WebPartFloatClear">
          &nbsp;
        </div>

        <div class="MiddleContent WebPartFloatLeft">
          <h3>Aspire Charter Academy</h3>

          <p>Gloria McDaniel-Hall<br />
          <br />
          ,&nbsp;,&nbsp;<br /></p>

          <p><a href=""></a><br />
          <a href="mailto:"></a></p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="dfwp-item">
        <div class="MiddleContent WebPartFloatRight">
          <h3>Lansing Charter Academy</h3>

          <p>Chris Thompson<br />
          <br />
          ,&nbsp;,&nbsp;<br /></p>

          <p><a href=""></a><br />
          <a href="mailto:"></a></p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="dfwp-item">
        <div class="WebPartFloatClear">
          &nbsp;
        </div>

        <div class="MiddleContent WebPartFloatLeft">
          <p>Paula Dowker<br />
          <br />
          ,&nbsp;,&nbsp;<br /></p>

          <p><a href=""></a><br />
          <a href="mailto:"></a></p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="dfwp-item">
        <div class="MiddleContent WebPartFloatRight">
          <h3>Aspire Charter Academy</h3>

          <p>Gloria McDaniel-Hall<br />
          <br />
          ,&nbsp;,&nbsp;<br /></p>

          <p><a href=""></a><br />
          <a href="mailto:"></a></p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="dfwp-item">
        <div class="WebPartFloatClear">
          &nbsp;
        </div>

        <div class="MiddleContent WebPartFloatLeft">
          <h3>Aspire Charter Academy</h3>

          <p>Gloria McDaniel-Hall<br />
          <br />
          ,&nbsp;,&nbsp;<br /></p>

          <p><a href=""></a><br />
          <a href="mailto:"></a></p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="dfwp-item">
        <div class="MiddleContent WebPartFloatRight">
          <h3>Pinnacle Academy</h3>

          <p>Ginny Schemrich<br />
          <br />
          ,&nbsp;,&nbsp;<br /></p>

          <p><a href=""></a><br />
          <a href="mailto:"></a></p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="dfwp-item">
        <div class="WebPartFloatClear">
          &nbsp;
        </div>

        <div class="MiddleContent WebPartFloatLeft">
          <h3>North Saginaw Charter Academy</h3>

          <p>Tonya Reed<br />
          <br />
          ,&nbsp;,&nbsp;<br /></p>

          <p><a href=""></a><br />
          <a href="mailto:"></a></p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="dfwp-item">
        <div class="MiddleContent WebPartFloatRight">
          <h3>Walker Charter Academy</h3>

          <p>Steve Bagley<br />
          <br />
          ,&nbsp;,&nbsp;<br /></p>

          <p><a href=""></a><br />
          <a href="mailto:"></a></p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="dfwp-item">
        <div class="WebPartFloatClear">
          &nbsp;
        </div>

        <div class="MiddleContent WebPartFloatLeft">
          <p>Paula Dowker<br />
          <br />
          ,&nbsp;,&nbsp;<br /></p>

          <p><a href=""></a><br />
          <a href="mailto:"></a></p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="dfwp-item">
        <div class="MiddleContent WebPartFloatRight">
          <p>Paula Dowker<br />
          <br />
          ,&nbsp;,&nbsp;<br /></p>

          <p><a href=""></a><br />
          <a href="mailto:"></a></p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="dfwp-item">
        <div class="WebPartFloatClear">
          &nbsp;
        </div>

        <div class="MiddleContent WebPartFloatLeft">
          <h3>Linden Charter Academy</h3>

          <p>Linda Caine-Smith<br />
          <br />
          ,&nbsp;,&nbsp;<br /></p>

          <p><a href=""></a><br />
          <a href="mailto:"></a></p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="dfwp-item">
        <div class="MiddleContent WebPartFloatRight">
          <h3>Chandler Woods Charter Academy</h3>

          <p>Barbara Lindquist<br />
          <br />
          ,&nbsp;,&nbsp;<br /></p>

          <p><a href=""></a><br />
          <a href="mailto:"></a></p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="dfwp-item">
        <div class="WebPartFloatClear">
          &nbsp;
        </div>

        <div class="MiddleContent WebPartFloatLeft">
          <h3>Aspire Charter Academy</h3>

          <p>Gloria McDaniel-Hall<br />
          4900 W. 15th Ave<br />
          Gary,&nbsp;IN,&nbsp;46406<br />
          219-944-7400</p>

          <p><a href=
          "http://aspire.heritageacademies.com">http://aspire.heritageacademies.com</a><br />

          <a href="mailto:email@email.com">email@email.com</a></p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="dfwp-item">
        <div class="MiddleContent WebPartFloatRight">
          <h3>Aspire Charter Academy</h3>

          <p>Gloria McDaniel-Hall<br />
          <br />
          ,&nbsp;,&nbsp;<br /></p>

          <p><a href=""></a><br />
          <a href="mailto:"></a></p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="dfwp-item">
        <div class="WebPartFloatClear">
          &nbsp;
        </div>

        <div class="MiddleContent WebPartFloatLeft">
          <h3>Chandler Woods Charter Academy</h3>

          <p>Barbara Lindquist<br />
          <br />
          ,&nbsp;,&nbsp;<br /></p>

          <p><a href=""></a><br />
          <a href="mailto:"></a></p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="dfwp-item">
        <div class="MiddleContent WebPartFloatRight">
          <h3>Linden Charter Academy</h3>

          <p>Linda Caine-Smith<br />
          3244 Linden Rd<br />
          Flint,&nbsp;MI,&nbsp;48504-1753<br />
          810-720-0515</p>

          <p><a href=
          "http://linden.heritageacademies.com/">http://linden.heritageacademies.com/</a><br />

          <a href="mailto:email@email.com">email@email.com</a></p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="dfwp-item">
        <div class="WebPartFloatClear">
          &nbsp;
        </div>

        <div class="MiddleContent WebPartFloatLeft">
          <h3>Chandler Woods Charter Academy</h3>

          <p>Barbara Lindquist<br />
          6895 Samrick Ave Private<br />
          Belmont,&nbsp;MI,&nbsp;49306-8844<br />
          616-866-6000</p>

          <p><a href=
          "http://chandlerwoods.heritageacademies.com/">http://chandlerwoods.heritageacademies.com/</a><br />

          <a href="mailto:email@email.com">email@email.com</a></p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="dfwp-item">
        <div class="MiddleContent WebPartFloatRight">
          <h3>Paragon Charter Academy</h3>

          <p>Kathy Watson<br />
          <br />
          ,&nbsp;,&nbsp;<br /></p>

          <p><a href=""></a><br />
          <a href="mailto:"></a></p>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: thanks for the formatting Keith, wasn't sure why it wasn't taking...

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure, what you define as "the same thing" or everything. So lets just create a function for it.

```
function whatISeeAsThing(node) { return node.innerHTML; }
//function whatISeeAsThing(node) { return $(node).find("h3").text(); } 
//...

function removeDuplicates() {
    var all = {};
    $.each($(".dfwp-column li"), function (i, node) {
        if (all[whatISeeAsThing(node)]) {
            $(node).remove();
        } else {
            all[whatISeeAsThing(node)] = true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I think he means the text within each h3 must be unique (must not be repeated in another h3).

Comment: I thought so. Did you recognize the out-commented function?

Comment: This one left duplicates.  For example, "Vanderbilt Academy" was there multiple times.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
var current;
$('li').each(function() {
    current = $(this);
    checkDoubles(current.next());    
});
function checkDoubles(oLi) {
    if(current.children('h3:first').text() == oLi.children('h3:first').text()) {
        checkDoubles(oLi.next());
        oLi.remove();
    }    
    checkDoubles(oLi.next());
}
```

Something like this might do the trick for you

Comment: Tried this one out, doesn't remove the duplicates.  I still see "Vanderbilt Charter Academy" multiple times.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for ya:-) http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/vA5HS/

```
$('.MiddleContent').each(function(){
    var h3 = $(this).children('h3').text();
    $(this).data('open',true)
        $('.MiddleContent').each(function(){
            if(($(this).data('open') == undefined || $(this).data('open') == false)){
                //console.log(h3, $(this).children('h3'), this)
                if(h3 == $(this).children('h3').text()){
                    //console.log('same');
                    $(this).remove();
                }
            }
        })
    $(this).data('open',false)
})
```

Comment: Tried this one, looks like it's removing anything that is unique.  I need it to leave the first one.  For example, there are multiple "Vanderbilt Charter Academy".  We want it to leave just one and remove the others.  This one seems to remove all of them.  Love jsFiddle by the way.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work too:

```
$("li.dfwp-item").each(function() {
    var text = $(this).find("h3:first").text();
    $("li.dfwp-item").not(this).each(function(){
        if($(this).find("h3:first").text() === text){
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: So does this remove the first one?  It seems like it removes all of them.  For example, "Vanderbilt Charter Academy".  If should leave at least one.